# Is it possible to create firefox addon ui inside tab?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have a chrome addon that I want to port to Firefox. This addon have a complex UI that takes entire page and it's intended to be opened and used for long periods of time, alongside with other pages opened in a browser. In chrome i just open ".html" addon interface file and it have access to all addon api: communication with addon scripts etc. But if i open ".html" file in firefox addon:

```
var root = data.url('icon.png').split('/').slice(0, -2).join('/');
widget.Widget({
  id: 'my-addon',
  label: 'my addon',
  contentURL: data.url('icon.png'),
  onClick: function() {
    tabs.open([root, 'lib', 'control.html'].join('/'));
  }
});
```

It seems javascript code inside a page don't have access to `this.port` object for communication. What is a correct way to create a full-page addon interface? Do I need to inject javascript code separatedly via `contentScriptFile` (very bad, since this is completely not possible in chrome and I will not be able to use same code for both addons) or use some special kind of `Panel` so it will be fullscreen?

Comment: I'm also looking for a way to load my html page which has full chrome access. I'm not sure how to do this. The way I do things right now kind of sucks. I listen to page load, and if its my html page than I `addEventListener`'s to it all. I dont like this method.

Comment: @Noitidart Post a non-addon SDK question if you like. I'm not going to my answer here, as things work completely differently in XUL/restartless add-ons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open the html page in a tab, and then use [`tab.attach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs#attach%28options%29) to attach the actual script(s). That way your scripts will be actual content scripts with access to the content script APIs.

```
widget.Widget({
  id: 'my-addon',
  label: 'my addon',
  contentURL: data.url('icon.png'),
  onClick: function() {
    tabs.open({
      url: data.url("control.html"),
      onOpen: function(tab) {
        tab.attach({
          contentScriptFile: [data.url("control.js")],
          onMessage: function() {}
        });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

It's ugly, but it should work (in general, I didn't actually try the example code).

Comment: Isn't it the same as using `contentScriptFile` with `tabs.open`?

Comment: The docs don't mention `contentScript*` being a valid option to `tabs.open()`, so even if there is such an undocumented API, I wouldn't wanna use it until it get officially documented.